# correct kernel source path

Tags: nvidia, kernel, cuda

I'm trying to install cuda6.5 using the .run file on an amazon aws gpu instance. I'm getting this error. I'm not sure what the kernel source path is. I did install it with `apt-get install linux-source and apt-get source linux-image-$(uname -r)` Does anyone know how to fix this issue? I tried `--kernel-source-path=/usr/src/linux-source-3.13.0` but it didn't work even though the sources are there.

```
The driver installation is unable to locate the kernel source. Please make sure that the kernel source packages are installed and set up correctly.
If you know that the kernel source packages are installed and set up correctly, you may pass the location of the kernel source with the '--kernel-source-path' flag.
```

Answer (score 4):

Install the header files:

```
sudo apt-get install linux-headers-$(uname -r) # or linux-headers-generic.
```

Since:

```
$ apt-cache show linux-source-3.13.0
Package: linux-source-3.13.0
...
Description-en: Linux kernel source for version 3.13.0 with Ubuntu patches
...
If you are simply trying to build third-party modules for your kernel,
you do not want this package. Install the appropriate linux-headers
package instead.
```

Answer (score 3):

I stumbled upon this problem when installing `CUDA 7.5 toolkit`. If you run the installer with `--verbose` flag, it will generate the log file with error details. In my case, the actual problem was with kernel source being compiled with newer version of `gcc` than was installed.

You are supposed to set environmental variable `IGNORE_CC_MISMATCH` to `1` to circumvent this check, but in my case that did not help, so I have to compile `CUDA 7.5` with `gcc-5.2` (with `--override` flag). Have not yet tested if this introduces any calculation errors (as google suggests).