# NVIDIA kernel installation fails on GeForce 310M

Tags: drivers, nvidia, kernel

This question is not a duplicate of the question [correct kernel source path](https://askubuntu.com/questions/537607/correct-kernel-source-path) There the problem was solved be installing the kernel header files. In my case the kernel header files are already installed.

Before you flag as duplicate: I believe I have read all sources to this topic and still the NVIDIA kernel module build fails with 'unable to locate kernel 
source'.

Ubuntu 14.04, trying to install
cuda_7.5.18_linux.run (md5sum: 4b3bcecf0dfc35928a0898793cf3e4c6)

```
~# uname -r
3.19.0-39-generic

~# ll /usr/src/
total 28
drwxr-xr-x  7 root root 4096 Dec 10 15:12 ./
drwxr-xr-x 10 root root 4096 Aug  5 01:12 ../
drwxr-xr-x 24 root root 4096 Dec  4 12:13 linux-headers-3.19.0-37/
drwxr-xr-x  7 root root 4096 Dec  4 12:13 linux-headers-3.19.0-37-generic/
drwxr-xr-x 24 root root 4096 Dec  7 09:45 linux-headers-3.19.0-39/
drwxr-xr-x  7 root root 4096 Dec  7 09:45 linux-headers-3.19.0-39-generic/
drwxr-xr-x  4 root root 4096 Dec 10 14:55 linux-source-3.13.0/
lrwxrwxrwx  1 root root   47 Nov 30 23:38 linux-source-3.13.0.tar.bz2 -> linux-source-3.13.0/linux-source-3.13.0.tar.bz2
```

When started with

```
~# sh cuda_7.5.18_linux.run
```

or

```
~# sh cuda_7.5.18_linux.run --linux-kernel-path /usr/src/linux-headers-3.19.0-39-generic/
```

installation fails with the same error: Unable to locate kernel sources...

Comment: Please see http://askubuntu.com/questions/537607/correct-kernel-source-path

Comment: I read this question/answer already. It says to install the header files which are there. The problem persists.

Comment: What type of GPU `Ex: GTX 980`

Comment: lspci: 01:00.0 VGA compatible controller: NVIDIA Corporation GT218M [GeForce 310M] (rev a2)

Comment: If you have tried and failed to install the nvidia drivers you may have a bunch of related garbage that's interfering. See: http://askubuntu.com/questions/481414/install-nvidia-driver-instead-nouveau/481540#481540

Comment: What version of Ubuntu do you have?

Comment: Ubuntu 14.04 (see question)

Comment: @ElderGeek I read that QA already. The nouveau driver is not the problem. I blacklisted that and rebooted the system and stopped the lightdm manager successfully.

Comment: Found a hint in the nvidia installer log. The 310M is not supported in CUDA 7.5. Instead there's a legacy driver that can be downloaded separately.

Comment: I just edited the answer for the legacy driver.

Answer (score 1):

First run:

```
wget http://developer.download.nvidia.com/compute/cuda/repos/ubuntu1404/x86_64/cuda-repo-ubuntu1404_7.0-28_amd64.deb
```

Then:

```
sudo dpkg -i cuda-repo-ubuntu1404_7.0-28_amd64.deb
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install cuda -y
```

After that, it should work.